# How to use external class when mapping objects in AutoMapper?

Tags: automapper, poco, dto

I've got an entity object, as well as DTO object that is used as an return type in the service layer of my application. I would like to use AutoMapper to map entity objects to DTO objects and vice-versa. One of my types, to perform mapping, needs some external class to act (i.e. provide translation for some string property). Is there any convenient way to do this in AutoMapper?

Comment: Yes, you can use dependency injection. The docs are [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dependency-injection).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, this example is what you want to do.
Based on a source property, AutoMapper is mapping an external translation to a destination property.

```
Dictionary<int, string> translations = new Dictionary<int, string>();
translations.Add(0, "Translation 0");
translations.Add(1, "Translation 1");
translations.Add(2, "Translation 2");

Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>().ForMember(a => a.Translation, b => b.MapFrom(c => translations[c.Id]));
});

Class1 src = new Class1()
{
    Id = 1
};
Class2 dest = Mapper.Map<Class1, Class2>(src);
```

Simple class structure:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }
}
```